# Date difference formatted in Days Hours Minutes Seconds

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to get the time remaining(difference) between two dates?

For example I'd like to have it return 6 days, 10 hours, 3 minutes and 37 seconds.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The following select should work:

```
DECLARE @x int, 
        @dt1 smalldatetime = '1996-03-25 03:24:16', 
        @dt2 smalldatetime = getdate()

SET @x = datediff (s, @dt1, @dt2)


SELECT convert(varchar, @x / (60 * 60 * 24)) + ':'
+ convert(varchar, dateadd(s, @x, convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01')), 108)
```

Another option that is closer to your desired output is:

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME ,
    @end DATETIME,
    @x INT

SELECT  @start = '2009-01-01' ,
        @end = DATEADD(ss, 5, DATEADD(mi, 52, DATEADD(hh, 18, DATEADD(dd, 2, @start)))),
        @x = DATEDIFF(s, @start, @end)

SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(dd, @start, @end)) + ' Days '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(hh, @start, @end) % 24) + ' Hours '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(mi, @start, @end) % 60) + ' Minutes '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(ss, DATEADD(s, @x, CONVERT(DATETIME2, '0001-01-01')))) + ' Seconds'
```

**UPDATED ANSWER (04/12/2018):** Accounts for difference in lower order date part that affects the higher order date part (i.e. 23 hour difference will now result in 0 days 23 hours)!

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME = '2018-04-12 15:53:33' ,
@end DATETIME = '2018-04-13 14:54:32' ,
@x INT;

SET @x = DATEDIFF(s, @start, @end);

SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( @x / 86400 )) + ' Days '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( @x % 86400 ) / 3600 )) + ' Hours '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( ( @x % 86400 ) % 3600 ) / 60 ))
        + ' Minutes ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ( ( ( @x % 86400 ) % 3600 ) % 60 ))
        + ' Seconds';
```

Comment: Second option is wrong when start hours/minutes/seconds is less then end.
Here is example with 23 hours difference:

select    CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(dd, '2018-04-12 15:54:32', '2018-04-13 14:54:32')) + ' Days '
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(hh, '2018-04-12 15:54:32', '2018-04-13 14:54:32') % 24) + ' Hours '

But the query returns 1 Day and 23 hours, not just 23 hours.

Comment: @TimofeyGMorozov Fixed with the updated answer.  Nice catch!

Answer (score 3):

Best way to display duration in **MS SQL DD:HH:MM:SS** for all records in the table

```
declare @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime

select @StartDate = '10/01/2012 23:40:18.000',@EndDate='10/04/2012 04:10:48.000'

select  convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)/86400)+':' +convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate,@EndDate)%86400/3600)+':'
+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, @startDate,@EndDate)%3600/60)+':'

+convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, @startDate, @EndDate)%60)) as [hh:mm:ss]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the [datediff](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function, getting the difference in seconds.  Then divide to get the number of days, etc.